# Error while Installing kimimaro 3.2.1 for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging, python-wheel

I am a newbie running pip version 22.1.2, Python 3.10 on Windows 11 (I also have Visual Studio Build Tools 2022).
I am trying to install the following Python Package: kimimaro 3.2.1 (https://pypi.org/project/kimimaro/).

I execute `pip install kimimaro` in cmd and I get the following error: "Failed building wheel for DracoPy" (full error message below). I tried installing DracoPy as a Python Package and it got installed successfully but it didn't help with the installation of kimimaro. I would be really thankful if someone had an idea how to solve this.

P.s I also have ninja installed, when I run `ninja --version` in cmd, the output is `1.10.2.git.kitware.jobserver-1`

Full Error message:

```
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for DracoPy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [512 lines of output]
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
        Running

         'C:/Users/CHRIST~1/AppData/Roaming/Python/PYTHON~1/Scripts/ninja.exe' '--version'

        failed with:

         Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
            return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
          File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
            exec(code, run_globals)
          File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\AppData\Roaming\Python\PYTHON~1\Scripts\ninja.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>

        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ninja'



      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 17 2022

      Generators
        Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                       Use -A option to specify architecture.
        Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                       Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
        Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                       Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
        Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                       Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
        Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                       Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
        Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                       Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
        Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                       Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
        Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
      * NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
        NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
        Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                       (experimental, work-in-progress).
        MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
        MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                       mingw32-make.
        Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
        Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
        Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
        CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
        CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
        CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles JOM
                                     = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
        CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
        CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
        CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
        CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
        CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
        CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
        Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                                     = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
        Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                                     = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
        Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
        Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                                     = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
        Kate - MinGW Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
        Kate - NMake Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
        Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
        Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
        Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                                     = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
        Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                                     = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
        Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
        Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.

      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
        Running

         'C:/Users/CHRIST~1/AppData/Roaming/Python/PYTHON~1/Scripts/ninja.exe' '--version'

        failed with:

         Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
            return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
          File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
            exec(code, run_globals)
          File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\AppData\Roaming\Python\PYTHON~1\Scripts\ninja.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>

        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ninja'



      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
        Generator

          Visual Studio 16 2019

        could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
        Running

         'C:/Users/CHRIST~1/AppData/Roaming/Python/PYTHON~1/Scripts/ninja.exe' '--version'

        failed with:

         Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
            return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
          File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
            exec(code, run_globals)
          File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\AppData\Roaming\Python\PYTHON~1\Scripts\ninja.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>

        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ninja'



      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
        Generator

          Visual Studio 15 2017

        could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.32.31332.0
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.32.31332.0
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Configuring done
      -- Generating done
      -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_cmake_test_compile/build
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.32.31332.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.32.31332.0
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Could NOT find Git (missing: GIT_EXECUTABLE)
      -- Could NOT find Git (missing: GIT_EXECUTABLE)
      -- Configuring done
      CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
        The object file directory

          C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/draco_compression_attributes_dec.dir/

        has 192 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
        characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

          src/draco/compression/attributes/sequential_attribute_decoders_controller.cc.obj

        cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
        correctly.


      CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
        The object file directory

          C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/draco_compression_point_cloud_dec.dir/

        has 193 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
        characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

          src/draco/compression/point_cloud/point_cloud_decoder.cc.obj

        cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
        correctly.


      CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
        The object file directory

          C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/draco_compression_bit_coders.dir/

        has 188 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
        characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

          src/draco/compression/bit_coders/adaptive_rans_bit_encoder.cc.obj

        cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
        correctly.


      CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
        The object file directory

          C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/draco_points_dec.dir/

        has 176 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
        characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

          src/draco/compression/point_cloud/algorithms/dynamic_integer_points_kd_tree_decoder.cc.obj

        cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
        correctly.


      CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
        The object file directory

          C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/draco_compression_attributes_enc.dir/

        has 192 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
        characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

          src/draco/compression/attributes/kd_tree_attributes_encoder.cc.obj

        cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
        correctly.


      CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
        The object file directory

          C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/draco_compression_attributes_pred_schemes_enc.dir/

        has 205 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
        characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

          src/draco/compression/attributes/prediction_schemes/prediction_scheme_encoder_factory.cc.obj

        cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
        correctly.


      CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
        The object file directory

          C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/draco_compression_point_cloud_enc.dir/

        has 193 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
        characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

          src/draco/compression/point_cloud/point_cloud_encoder.cc.obj

        cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
        correctly.


      CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
        The object file directory

          C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/draco_points_enc.dir/

        has 176 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
        characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

          src/draco/compression/point_cloud/algorithms/dynamic_integer_points_kd_tree_encoder.cc.obj

        cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
        correctly.


      CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
        The object file directory

          C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/draco_compression_attributes_pred_schemes_dec.dir/

        has 205 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
        characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

          draco_compression_attributes_pred_schemes_dec.cc.obj

        cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
        correctly.


      -- Generating done
      CMake Warning:
        Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

          PYTHON_EXECUTABLE
          PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR
          PYTHON_LIBRARY
          PYTHON_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS
          PYTHON_VERSION_STRING
          Python3_EXECUTABLE
          Python3_INCLUDE_DIR
          Python3_LIBRARY
          Python3_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS
          Python_EXECUTABLE
          Python_INCLUDE_DIR
          Python_LIBRARY
          Python_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS
          SKBUILD


      -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bqcqeazy/dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.10/cmake-build
      Warning: NMake does not support parallel builds. Ignoring parallel build command line option.
      Scanning dependencies of target draco_compression_attributes_dec
      [  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/draco_compression_attributes_dec.dir/src/draco/compression/attributes/attributes_decoder.cc.obj
      attributes_decoder.cc
      [  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/draco_compression_attributes_dec.dir/src/draco/compression/attributes/kd_tree_attributes_decoder.cc.obj
      kd_tree_attributes_decoder.cc
      [  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/draco_compression_attributes_dec.dir/src/draco/compression/attributes/sequential_attribute_decoder.cc.obj
      sequential_attribute_decoder.cc
      C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqcqeazy\dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4\draco\src\draco\compression\attributes\sequential_attribute_decoder.cc : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: '': Invalid argument
      NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2022\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1432~1.313\bin\Hostx86\x64\cl.exe' : return code '0x1'
      Stop.
      NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
      Stop.
      NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
      Stop.
        File "C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rfi6lu0w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
          cmkr.make(make_args, install_target=cmake_install_target, env=env)
        File "C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rfi6lu0w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 680, in make
          self.make_impl(clargs=clargs, config=config, source_dir=source_dir, install_target=install_target, env=env)
        File "C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rfi6lu0w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 704, in make_impl
          raise SKBuildError(


      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143" generator
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      -- Trying "Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142" generator
   
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141" generator
      --------------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator
      --------------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator - success
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      Configuring Project
        Working directory:
          C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqcqeazy\dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4\_skbuild\win-amd64-3.10\cmake-build
        Command:
          cmake 'C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqcqeazy\dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4\draco' -G 'NMake Makefiles' '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqcqeazy\dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4\_skbuild\win-amd64-3.10\cmake-install' -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.10.5 -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE '-DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rfi6lu0w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\skbuild\resources\cmake' '-DPython3_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' '-DPython3_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=C:\Program Files\Python310\Include' '-DPython3_LIBRARY:PATH=C:\Program Files\Python310\libs\python310.lib' '-DPython3_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rfi6lu0w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include' '-DPython_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' '-DPython_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=C:\Program Files\Python310\Include' '-DPython_LIBRARY:PATH=C:\Program Files\Python310\libs\python310.lib' '-DPython_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rfi6lu0w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include' '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' '-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=C:\Program Files\Python310\Include' '-DPYTHON_LIBRARY:PATH=C:\Program Files\Python310\libs\python310.lib' '-DPYTHON_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rfi6lu0w\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release

      Traceback (most recent call last):

      An error occurred while building with CMake.
        Command:
          cmake --build . --target install --config Release --
        Install target:
          install
        Source directory:
          C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqcqeazy\dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4
        Working directory:
          C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqcqeazy\dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4\_skbuild\win-amd64-3.10\cmake-build
      Please check the install target is valid and see CMake's output for more information.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for DracoPy
Failed to build DracoPy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for DracoPy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
```

...
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Users\Christian Nikolov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqcqeazy\dracopy_60a7e1f4eb4e4964900b2b203c0cc8b4\_skbuild\win-amd64-3.10\cmake-build\CMakeFiles\draco_compression_attributes_pred_schemes_enc.dir\src\draco\compression\attributes\prediction_schemes'

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors).

Comment: Sorry, I am going to correct it in a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve the issue with the help of one of kimimaro's creators. DracoPy had an installation problem for python 3.10. It worked fine on python 3.9, which also allowed for a successful kimimaro installation : )